# preserve click state of fixed left menu

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

i have a side navigation which has side menu.When i click something in the menu the corresponding details are rendered in the right.

The menu has submenus so when i click menu submenus are also visible.

Now when i reload the page i am able to preserve the right side details but submenus are hidden. How can i preserve that.

HTML

```
<nav class="sidebar">
    <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let tenant of tenants ;trackBy: trackId">
        <div class="nested-menu">
            <a [routerLink]="['../tenant', tenant.id ]" class="list-group-item" (click)="addExpandClass(tenant.id)">
                <span><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp; {{tenant.name}}</span>
            </a>
            <li class="nested" [ngClass]="{'expand' : showMenu === tenant.id }">
                <ul class="submenu" *ngFor="let dataConfiguration of tenant.dataConfigurations ;trackBy: trackId">
                    <li>
                        <a href><span>{{dataConfiguration.name}}</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </div>       
    </ul>
</nav>
```

side menu JS

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
    selector: 'sidebar-cmp',
    templateUrl: 'sidebar.html',
    styleUrls: [
        'sidebar.scss'
    ]
})

export class SidebarComponent {
    @Input() tenants = 0;
    showMenu: string = '';

    addExpandClass( element: any ) {
        if ( element === this.showMenu ) {
            this.showMenu = '0';
        } else {
            this.showMenu = element;
        }
    }
}
```

Parent HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <sidebar-cmp [tenants] = "tenants"></sidebar-cmp>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You want the submenus to be shown when reloading the page?

Comment: @Kinduser : yes

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`routerLinkActive` directive](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html), if the relevant link gets a specific class, you may be able to target everything else using that class (or even apply the class to the submenu etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below HTML

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <nav class="sidebar">
            <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let tenant of tenants ;trackBy: trackId">
                <div class="nested-menu">
                    <a [routerLink]="['../tenant', tenant.id ]" class="list-group-item" (click)="addExpandClass(tenant.id)">
                        <span><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> &nbsp; {{tenant.name}}</span>
                    </a>
                    <li class="nested" [ngClass]="{'expand' : showMenu === tenant.id }">
                        <ul class="submenu" *ngFor="let dataConfiguration of tenant.dataConfigurations ;trackBy: trackId">
                            <li>
                                <a [routerLink]="['...']"><span>{{dataConfiguration.name}}</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </div>       
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Define your routes in the appmodule.ts file.

As per your comment below, handling the toggle between the menu is not possible during page refresh. You can have the properties for the respective menu in your **tenatnts** to retain the state. However, after page refresh the components loads freshly as earlier. So your data will be lost.

This is possible only if you are using state retaining mechanisms which is a overhead for just a menu click expansion.

Comment: I need to trigger this on page load i think (click)="addExpandClass(tenant.id)"

Comment: So what you mentioned i already have this. I updated to make it more clear. So the problem is not the right hand side. The problem is with the left side submenus.  When i reload they are not in expanded form if previously they were in expanded form. If i dont reload the page than everything is fine and works.

Comment: So for example in the image if i expand test menu and than if i reload than after reload i dont see the test menu in expanded form. I want them to be the expanded form. Right side is okay since i think is handled by router

Comment: That is not a good practice, as the toggling is handled in the bootstrap.js.

Comment: So please tell the best practice